jackson pass 0 to constructor instead of throw exception when property is absent
I have request as
{
 "name" : "test"
}

RequestDTO like this
data class DTO (
val name: String
val maxValue: Long
)

expected : Json serialisation fail due to missing property maxValue.
what is happening: Jackson sets maxValue = 0;
I tried to use property DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES
but
IT DOESN'T WORK IF PROPERTY IS ABSENT. IT WORKS ONLY IF YOU HAVE EXPLICIT NULL ON REQUESTS
Jackson deserialization of missing JSON number value to 0.0 in Spring
has wrong answer
@JsonProperty(required = true)

Isn't a solution because I need global configuration to prohibit convert absence value to zeros.

Does this answer your question? How do you make Jackson use Kotlin default params for missing values?

You can use
jacksonObjectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES)

It makes error slightly different but you will receive 400 bad requests as expected

Do you mean 400 Bad request? (404 means file not found)

yes I meant 400 my typo

From what I am getting you want a bad request when maxValue isn't passed,
I couldn't find the perfect solution but this will work for now until I find something better.
add these to your pom.xml or gradle(version to your gradle build)
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

update your DTO data class to:
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull

data class Dto(
        @field:NotNull(message = "cannot be null")
        val name: String,
        @field:NotNull( message = "must not be null")
        val maxValue: Long?
)

and your controller should look something like this:
import com.example.demo.dto.Dto
import jakarta.validation.Valid
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class HelloController {

    @PostMapping
    fun postData(@Valid @RequestBody dto: Dto): Dto {
        return dto
    }
}

this will throw a Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException
{
   "name": "test"
}

which will resolve to Bad request response like this:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-06-19T11:04:10.776+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "path": "/"
}

Unfortunately, the error response doesn't also show the message attached to the Annotation.  Hopefully, you can find a way to fix that using @ExceptionHandler
Ideally, the error would have looked like this
{
  "errors": [
    "Name cannot be null",
    "maxValue cannot be null"
  ]
}

reference here

From what I understood, I think the OP actually wants the deserialization to throw an exception if there is a missing value in the JSON data. His question if confusing because he talks about null, when there are no nulls involved. But he does say he expects the deserialization to fail.

I want bad request because no value presents.
missing value != null.
Edited exception example

I have updated my answer ... check the new solution

The solution above will work, cause Kotlin will set the value of null to 0 and the @Min will catch it which will through 400, you can try the solution and see. remember your maxValue doesn't have the nullable symbol.

max value can be 0 or negative.

I have updated the code to work with 0 and negative numbers.
